# How to give only the values which is allowed during paste in angular8

Tags: angular

I have used pipe filter selector and it will restrict all special characters except - now during copy paste in the input field it is restricting special characters in input field but in the event it is not restricting  the special characters. In `wildCardSearch` i am able to see special characters as  well.

DEMO:[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsrmzn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

For testing:
`Testing#`, if we paste in input box, it takes only `Testing`, but while displaying it takes `Testing#`.

I tried giving selector in the button as well but didnt work.

TS:

```
  public searchChange(event) {
    this.wildCardSearch = event;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button">{{wildCardSearch}}</button>
```

Comment: remove `appInputRestriction` from `input`

Comment: Thanks for response, i want what ever is visible in search, should be displayed in wildcardSearch binding, by restricting the special characters

Comment: didn't clear what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Use [NgControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl) to set value of input form control.

> A base class that all control FormControl-based directives extend. It
>   binds a FormControl object to a DOM element

**Try this**

```
export class InputRestrictionDirective {

  regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    console.log('KeyBoard');
   if ( this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart === 0 && event.key === ' ' ) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
    if (!RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      this.control.control.setValue(value);
      event.preventDefault();
    }, 100)
  }

}
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpofg5)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how to prevent the actual paste event from triggering! event.preventDefault() is important, to make sure no unexpected/unwanted side effects occur when pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in template give a template Ref variable to your input `#inputValue`

```
  <div class="d-flex">
                <input type="text" class="form-control min-w300" placeholder="Search Agent" [(ngModel)]="wildCardSearch" (ngModelChange)="searchChange($event)" appInputRestriction #inputValue>
            </div>
```

In .ts use  setTimeout

```
@ViewChild('inputValue',{static : false}) el:ElementRef; 
public searchChange(event) {    
      setTimeout(() => {  
        this.wildCardSearch = this.el.nativeElement.value
    }, 100)      
  }
```